# Get value of checkbox by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I need to get the value of a checkbox by name.  I have the following code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_checkbox" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox" id="my_checkbox_id" value="1"  />
```

The idea is that if the checkbox is not checked, I would get the value of the input type hidden (which is 0).

Here is what I have tried but did not work:

```
$('input[name=my_checkbox]').val();
```

However this returned the value of both the hidden input and checkbox.  Can anyone tell me how I can get the value of the checkbox when checked (1) or else get the value of the hidden input (0) when unchecked?  I guess this has to be done by name so that if the checkbox is unchecked, I get the value of the hidden input as if the checkbox is unchecked you won't get its value.

Comment: I'd put an ID on the hidden element, so that I can retrieve both elements independently.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, will your values always be `0` and `1` ?

Comment: @roXon yes if the checkbox is checked, it will be 1, otherwise it will be 0.

This does not apply to 1 checkbox only, I have a set of checkboxes which will do the same thing

Comment: Than why you need the `0` valued checkbox (hidden one)? you don't need it at all.

Comment: @roXon this value is being stored in the database so on page load I check/uncheck the checkboxes as required

Comment: all clear, but you don't need AT ALL the hidden one. Just create a statement that will tell: if not checked that value = 0 ;

Comment: @roXon if the checkbox is unchecked, then a NULL value is returned to the database.  I need to make sure that "0" is sent instead

Comment: Take a look http://jsbin.com/efuvos/1/edit or this one if one checkbox is checked http://jsbin.com/efuvos/2/edit

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21998/discussion-between-user1809790-and-roxon)

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_checkbox" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox" id="my_checkbox_id" value="1"  />
```

Try this it worked for me:

```
$( 'input[name="my_checkbox"]:checked' ).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do this:

```
if($("#my_checkbox_id").is(':checked')) {
    output = $("#my_checkbox_id").val();
} else {
    output = $('input[type=hidden]').val();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just find the `:visible` checkbox:

```
$('input[name="my_checkbox"]:visible').change(function() {
  if ($('input[name="my_checkbox"]:visible').is(':checked')) {
    alert($('input[name="my_checkbox"]:visible').val());
  } else {
    alert($('input[name="my_checkbox"]:hidden').val());
  }
});
```

tryout the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JgzGa/1/

Comment: this returns always 1 even when the checkbox is unchecked

Comment: @roXon plz see the updated fiddle and the answer. Yes just missed reading the question properly, apologies for that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need the hidden one, you just need to say:
`if checkbox is not checked set his value to '0'`
 and this is all you need:

```
$('input:checkbox').not(':checked').val(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new function for it:

```
$.fn.checkboxVal = function() {
    var checked = $(this).filter("[type=checkbox]:checked");
    if (checked.length)
        return checked.val();

    return $(this).filter("[type=hidden]").val();
};
```

Then you can say `$("input[name=foo]").checkboxVal()` and it'll get you the correct value.

Untested, so fixing any bugs is left as an exercise for the reader.